# Comparisons: "so [adjective/adverb] as" or "as [adjective/adverb] as"

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

When learning how to make comparisons, students of English as a foreign language are first told to use the structure "as [adjective/adverb] as". However, at higher levels, they are told that both options ("as/so [adjective/adverb] as") are correct.

I've been wondering if there are any differences between them, but I can't find an answer in my grammar (Cambridge Grammar of English). In a school book, I saw two examples that led me to think that:

1. "as [adverb] as" is possible with both positive and negative sentences
2. "so [adverb] as" is only possible in negative sentences

Is this correct?
If so, does it also apply to adjectives?

Examples for adjectives:

- This is as good as that.
- This is so good as that.
- This isn't as good as that.
- This isn't so good as that.

Examples for adverbs:

- Anne plays as well as John.
- Anne plays so well as John. (not correct?)
- Anne doesn't play as well as John.
- Anne doesn't play so well as John.

Comment: Could you possibly provide some examples of what you mean?

Comment: Is '_This is so good as that._' a grammatical sentence? You haven't added '_(not correct?)_' to the sentence, unlike in the case of the sentence '_Anne plays so well as John._', which contradicts your statement '_However, at higher levels, they are told that both options ("as/so [adjective/adverb] as") are correct._'. If you now understand the concept of '_as...as..._' and '_so...as..._', could you explain to me your reasoning? I myself am learning English and some explanations would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. *So* is an alternative to *as* in this construction in negative contexts, but not otherwise. I don't use it in my idiolect, but many people do.

Comment: "Anne doesn't play so well as John" sounds completely wrong to my British ears. It may be acceptable in other countries, but I would view this as grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The rule as I learned it from an anecdote about Walter Lippmann's anger when a writer failed to follow it is this:

> Use "as" in positive comparisons, "so" in negative comparisons.

Examples:

- I am as tall as she, but not so tall as he.
- I am hardly so stingy as that, though I am as thrifty as one should be.
- The cars today are not so fast as they once were.